# Why i am able to add a new item even if i have a Required field which is hidden inside the New form,

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

Inside the content type I set a field as required inside my SharePoint online site as follow:-
[image]

and using PnP i set the field to be hidden in new form, as follow:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ctx = Get-PnPContext
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field = Get-PnPField -Identity "LineManager"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

now when i add a new item inside the list i thought that i will get an error since the new form is missing a required field, but i was able to save the item even if the new form is missing a required filed.. so can anyone advice how SharePoint handle this?

Comment: Hidden columns are not rendered on the form (data entry/edit) and that's why validation on those columns is not performed when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

SetShowInNewForm($false) does not change the column status to "hidden", its status is still shown as Required in the content type.

PnP PowerShell to Hide a Field at Content Type Level:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com"
$ContentTypeName ="Crescent Project V2"
$FieldName = "ProjectManager" #Internal Name
 
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get the Client Context
$Context = Get-PnPContext
  
#Get the content type
$ContentType = Get-PnPContentType -Identity $ContentTypeName -ErrorAction Stop
  
#Get the Field from Content Type
$ContentTypeField = $ContentType.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($FieldName)
$Context.Load($ContentTypeField)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
  
#Set Hidden Property of the field
$ContentType.FieldLinks.GetById($ContentTypeField.Id).Hidden = $True
$ContentType.Update($True) #Update Children
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host -f Green "Field '$($ContentTypeField.Title)' Set to Hidden!"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but your answer is not related to my question

Comment: Like Matiur Ra​​hman said, when you run SetShowInNewForm($false), this still makes the column required, it just doesn't display in the form, so you need to set the hidden property of the field to make the error disappear.

Comment: but i am not getting any error, i am asking a different question

Comment: I know you could save the new item, however there is a required filed notification in red in that item, I have tested it and has the same result with you, so I say SetShowInNewForm($false) not solve the issue of required filed.